# laravel eloquent whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this query,

```
$listings = Tag::whereHas('listings', function($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('moderated', 1)
                    ->where('active', 1)
                    ->where('cost', '=', '0.00')
                    ->orWhere('cost', '=', NULL)
                    ->with(['types' => function($q) {
                      $q->whereIn('type_id', [1]);
                    }])
                    ->with('primaryImage');
                })->get();
```

This returns the expected tags, however it does not return the expected listings, the relationships looks like this,

`tag` and `listings` have a `n:n` relationship
`listing` and `type` have a `n:n` relationship

What I am wanting to achieve is query the data for all tags that have listings that have a cost of `0.00` or `NULL` and also have a type of 1 based on its `n:n` relationship.

What I am getting however is `tags` are being returned that have `listings` (courtesy of the whereHas) but the listing isn't actually part of the response, and if I do `$query->with('listings')` it seems to disregard my cost where clause and return all `listings` in that `tag`?

Any ideas of how I can get all tags that have listings and those listings to be selected via whether their cost is zero and if there type (`n:n` relationship) is `1` (or anything other number)

Comment: I guess `Tag::with('listings','type')->whereHas('type',function ...)->whereHas('listings',function...)` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

In `Laravel` and `MySql` you can not do `column = null`, you have to use `column is null` in `MySql`. Therefor `Laravel` also has special condition for this, instead use `whereNull()`. So change the cost where to the following.

```
->orWhereNull('cost')
```